# API naming conventions for data actions

Tags: elasticsearch, naming-conventions, grpc, api-design

I am building a gRPC service that is responsible for creating and deleting network events data. 
The API should get as an input a list of network events, do some processing, and save the results in Elasticsearch as JSON,
 an input example:

```
{"source" : "1.2.3.4" , "destination" : "3.4.5.6", "numberOfPackets" : 12345, "Protocol" : "TCP"}.
```

Normal verb+noun API naming conventions (CreateNetworkEvent) feels a little off for this scenario since i am nor "creating" an instance of anything. It does not have an ID and it cannot be retrieved directly. It will be used later in filters,aggregration,etc.

Is there a naming convention for this type of action?

Answer (score 0):

GCP has [some recommendations](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/naming_convention) for APIs that are fronted by both gRPC and REST. Those would recommend the name `CreateNetworkEvent`, though it would *also* recommend that the response to this RPC return the data necessary to invoke a `GetNetworkEvent` method.

RPC is semantically less strict than REST. If your API doesn't have resource-oriented semantics, then you should be able to use any sort of verb-noun combination you like. Perhaps `RecordEvent`?